# What are some 'Rule of thumb' to follow when creating your folder structure for your MEAN stack project

Tags: mean-stack

Over the past 3 months, I have been learning the MEAN stack for a class that I am undertaking at University. During this time, I have focused on tutorials as a source of learning to grasp the MEAN stack.

I’ve been beginning to notice that some tutorials have slight variations in their folder structure to others.
Below are two project structures that I’ve worked on.

Example 1: Photo of file structure example 1

[image]

Example 2: Photo of file structure example 2

[image]

I know this is a subjective area, so my question today is, **What are some of the ‘rules of thumb’ to follow when creating your folder structure for your MEAN stack project.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

with open source , you put the rules which make you comfort and create your own structure there's no rule for this and all instructors just they create what they like because there's no standard structure, so choose what you like. this is my opinion.